# DELETE button on Django Python

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to have the DELETE button work right away on the table (add.stock_html template), instead of opening up another URL (page).
I don't want to send to delete_stock.html URL.
I've tried many ways, it seems that the problem might be on the delete_stock.html template.
Any clues on how to solve it?!
I have attached the images.

add_stock.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table
      class="table align-middle table-hover table-bordered"
      id="example"
      style="text-align: center"
    >
      <thead class="table-dark thead-default" style="align-items: center">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
          <th scope="col">Previous Close</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Change $</th>
          <th scope="col">Change %</th>
          <th scope="col">52Wk Low</th>
          <th scope="col">52Wk High</th>
          <th scope="col">YTD %</th>
          <th scope="col">Market Cap</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% if ticker %} {% for list_item in output %}
        <tr>
          <th>{{ list_item.companyName }}</th>
          <td>{{ list_item.symbol }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ list_item.previousClose }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ list_item.latestPrice }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ list_item.change }}</td>
          <td>{{ list_item.changePercentage }} %</td>
          <td>$ {{ list_item.week52Low }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ list_item.week52High }}</td>
          <td>{{ list_item.ytdChange }} %</td>
          <td>$ {{ list_item.marketCap }}</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_stock' %}"
              ><i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can" aria-hidden="true"></i
            ></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %} {% endif %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

delete_stock.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}
<h1>Delete Stock</h1>
<br /><br />

{% if ticker %} 
{% for item in ticker %}
<a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary"
  >Delete {{ item }}</a
>
<br /><br />
{% endfor %} 
{% else %} 
    You don't have any stocks... 
{% endif %} 
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("add_stock.html", views.add_stock, name="add_stock"),
    path("delete/<stock_id>", views.delete, name="delete"),
    path("delete_stock.html", views.delete_stock, name="delete_stock"),
]
```

views.py

```py
def home(request):
    import requests 
    import json 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ticker = request.POST['ticker']
        api_request = requests.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + ticker + "/quote?token=<YOUR_KEY>")

        try:
            api = json.loads(api_request.content)
        except Exception as e:
            api = "Error..."
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'api': api})

    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'ticker': "Enter a Ticker Symbol Above or Stock Quote..."})    

def add_stock(request):
    import requests 
    import json 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StockForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ("Stock added successfully!"))
            return redirect('add_stock')

    else:  
        ticker = Stock.objects.all()
        output = []
        for ticker_item in ticker:
            api_request = requests.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + str(ticker_item) + "/quote?token=<YOUR_KEY>")
            try:
                api = json.loads(api_request.content)
                output.append(api)
            except Exception as e:
                api = "Error..."
       
        return render(request, 'add_stock.html', {'ticker': ticker, 'output': output})

def delete(request, stock_id):
    item = Stock.objects.get(pk=stock_id)
    item.delete()
    messages.success(request, f"{item} deleted successfully!")
    return redirect("add_stock")


def delete_stock(request):
    ticker = Stock.objects.all()
    return render(request, "delete_stock.html", {"ticker": ticker})
```

[image: add_stock.html]

[image: delete_stock.html]

Comment: if you want to delete without reloading page then you need `JavaScript` with `fetch("/delete_stock", ...)`. And you should send ID of this row to `/delete_stock` because it doesn't know what to delete. ie `/delete_stock?id=NVDA`

Answer (score 0):

`delete` view is okay, but you are not pointing to it, instead its directed to another view called `delete_stock`:

```
...
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_stock' %}"
    ><i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can" aria-hidden="true"></i
    ></a>
</td>
...
```

And, that view lists your items instead of deleting it, and also renders the wrong page:

```py
def delete_stock(request):
    ticker = Stock.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'delete_stock.html', {'ticker': ticker})
```

So, just point to the right one:

```
...
<td>
<a
    class="btn btn-danger"
    href="{% url 'delete' list_item.id %}"
    ><i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can" aria-hidden="true"></i
></a>
</td>
...
```

Rename `delete_stock` view to `add_stock` (also render the correct template) and adjust your `urls` accordingly:

views.py

```py
def delete(request, stock_id):
    item = Stock.objects.get(pk=stock_id)
    item.delete()
    messages.success(request, f'{item} deleted successfully!')
    return redirect('add_stock')

def add_stock(request):
    ticker = Stock.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'add_stock.html', {'ticker': ticker})
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("stock/add", views.add_stock, name="add_stock"),
    path("stock/delete/<stock_id>", views.delete, name="delete"),
]
```

Comment: I've already have a add_stock view, i think i might have deleted when trying to post/edit my question in the first place.

Comment: Its more of a list view anyways, just rename it to `list_stock` and render the correct page then!